# Crash Android Program On OpenCV Core.DCT() Method

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I want to write an android program to compute dct of the input image, and I am using opencv android framework. first of all I convert input image to grayscale and then i want to compute dct using Core.dct() with 16*16 block. this is the dct computation part :

```
int rownum = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= M - B + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= N - B + 1; j++) {
            Mat SubImg = GrayImage.submat(new Range(i, i+B-1), new Range(j, j+B-1));
            Mat Block_DCT = Mat.zeros(16, 16, SubImg.type());
            Mat Block_DCT_Quantized = Mat.zeros(16, 16, Block_DCT.type());

            Core.dct(SubImg, Block_DCT);
            Core.divide(Block_DCT, SQ16, Block_DCT_Quantized);
            Mat row = Mat.zeros(1, B*B, Block_DCT_Quantized.type());
            Block_DCT_Quantized.reshape(1, B*B);

            rownum=rownum+1;
        }
    }
```

I debug the code and figure out that the application crash on the line Core.dct() !!!
i don't know what is the problem, but I suppose it's because of input type ...

can any body help me ? what should I do ?

Update :

I found the solution, the problem was because of size and type of Mat objects, actually Core.dct() method just work with this type Mat: cv_64fc1. I use SubImg.convertTo() function to change the type and correct the size of block, so it worked...
thanks to Rui Marques for answering...

Comment: Post logcat error message. Maybe somehow your algorithm makes SubImg smaller than Block_DCT. Print those matrixes sizes to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dct needs *float* input.

you have to convert your image to CvType.CV_32F or  CvType.CV_64F before applying dct / dft